# MySQL update column with sequential numbers grouped by a field with the same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to do a massive update in a column of my MySQL table using as reference one field that has the same value. The **update** is a number sequence that repeats when grouped.

**MySQL Version:**

> 5.6.41-84.1

**MySQL Table:**

> sis_coautoria

**Columns and values**

```
id_auto_coautoria | id_coautor | hierarquia_coautoria | id_trabalho

1, 1, null, 123
2, 43, null, 123
3, 2, null, 123
4, 2, null, 100
5, 1, null, 675
6, 50, null, 100
```

I want to update the **hierarquia_coautoria** column using the **id_trabalho** column as reference and **id_auto_coautoria** as ORDER BY. The expected result is something like this:

```
id_auto_coautoria | id_coautor | hierarquia_coautoria | id_trabalho

1, 1, 1, 123
2, 43, 2, 123
3, 2, 3, 123
4, 2, 1, 100
6, 50, 2, 100
5, 1, 1, 675
```

The rows with id_trabalho = 123 are update with *1, 2, 3*; id_trabalho = 100 are update with *1, 2* and so on.

---

*There is another table with **id_trabalho column** as reference if needed.

**Other MySQL Table**

```
sis_trabalhos

id_auto_trabalho | id_trabalho

1, 123
2, 100
3, 675
```

**So, I tried something like this:**

```
SET @rank:=0;
UPDATE sis_coautoria
INNER JOIN sis_trabalhos ON sis_coautoria.id_trabalho = sis_trabalhos.id_trabalho
SET sis_coautoria.hierarquia_coautoria=@rank:=@rank+1;
```

**The result:**

```
id_auto_coautoria | id_coautor | hierarquia_coautoria | id_trabalho

1, 1, 1, 123
2, 43, 2, 123
3, 2, 3, 123
4, 2, 4, 100
5, 1, 5, 675
6, 50, 6, 100
...
```

The result was a number sequence that ignore the id_trabalho condition to be the same value.

---

PS.: How can I show MySQL table with friendly view like this[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand is that you need the row number for a group of id_trabalho columns. Since Mysql 5 doesn't have CTE, you could use subqueries to perform the same.

```
    update sis_coautoria a
join 
(SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @id_trabalho = id_trabalho THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS rn,
    @id_trabalho:=id_trabalho as id_trabalho,
    id_auto_coautoria
FROM
    sis_coautoria
ORDER BY id_auto_coautoria)
cte on a.id_auto_coautoria=cte.id_auto_coautoria
set a.hierarquia_coautoria=cte.rn
```

note: I have not run this query on an editor.

Comment: note: MySQL-5.6 doesn't have CTEs, its a MySQL-8.0+ feature.

Comment: Yeap! I had this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte AS

I will search something correlated.

Comment: @BlackSwan I got this error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by id_trabalho order by id_auto_coautoria asc) rn
from sis_coautoria)
c' at line 3

Comment: Looks like window functions are not supported in MySQL 5. Let me check if there is an equivalent to window functions in MySQL

Comment: @BlackSwan the hierarquia_coautoria column is update to "1" for every row. There is no sequence.

Comment: in the subquery, update the order by clause to ORDER BY id_trabalho,id_auto_coautoria. Run only the subquery and check if you are getting the correct sequence numbers. Refer this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: @BlackSwan the result is rn = "1" for every row.

Comment: @RenatoPirei: If you found the suggestion or answer helpful, upvote and mark as completed

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT**
This answer is for **MySQL 5**. **MySQL 8 (or newer)** has other methods to get the same results.

@BlackSwan contribuition helped me to get the answer for my question. Thank you!

My **MySQL server version is 5.6** and doesn't allow number_row() function or CTEs procedures. So, the solution was emulate MySQL ROW_NUMBER() function with a subquery to populate a new column "*sequencia*" that was use to update my desired column (**hierarquia_coautoria**).

**Here the code to get the desire results:**

```
update sis_coautoria a
join 
(SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @trabalhoID = id_trabalho THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS sequencia,
    @trabalhoID:=id_trabalho as trabalho_id,
    id_coautor_auto,
    id_usuario
FROM
    sis_coautoria,(SELECT @trabalhoID:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
ORDER BY id_trabalho ASC)
cte on a.id_coautor_auto=cte.id_coautor_auto
set a.hierarquia_coautoria=cte.sequencia
```

**Code explanation:**

We use a variable (@row_number) to storage the row's counting number following this condition: when *trabalho_id* has the same value, a new line number will be add in numeric sequential way in *sequencia* column.

```
@row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @trabalhoID = id_trabalho THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS sequencia
```

In sequence, We use a condition to join the referenced columns and update the desired column (*hierarquia_coautoria*) with the value stored in *sequencia* column.

```
cte on a.id_coautor_auto=cte.id_coautor_auto
    set a.hierarquia_coautoria=cte.sequencia
```

**Other information:**

link to [row_number() emulation tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

link to [ROW_NUMBER() function in MySQL 8](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

[About CTE (MySQL 8+)](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/)

Comment: . . These answers are not correct because you are assigning a variable and using it in different expressions in the `SELECT`.  MySQL explicitly does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`, so even if this code seems to work now on your particular data, it is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: You are correct, but the answer indicates a path to solve the problem. We indicated how to get a possible solution trough MySQL functions and procedures.